# Cannot clone git from Azure DevOps using PAT

Tags: git, authentication, azure-devops, token, access-token

I cannot clone a simple repository from Azure DevOps.
OS: Ubuntu 18.10

I do this:

- Got to Azure DevOps
- Click on the top right corner on my user name
- Go to the security tab
- Create a PAT with all the scope (to be sure there is no scope
  problem)
- Copy the PAT to the clipboard
- Paste the PAT somewhere else to confirm the PAT has been copied correctly (I know... not safe but that is out of the scope of this question)
- Go to my console
- Issue: `git clone https://myorganization.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo/`
- I enter the user name and the password (the PAT)

I keep getting this message from Git:
`fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myorganization.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo/'`

I was reading the solutions of other people but none worked for me.
I also tried this:

- Pass the token in the form https://usename:token@myorganization.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo/ I am really surprised people say this worked... for my git complains
  because believes the : means the port.
- Tried to
  activate/deactivate credential manager of git  * Tried on Windows and
  Ubuntu.
- Tried to activate and deactivate the simple credentials.
- Tried with the simple credentials, i.e. username + password.
- Tried to put my user name in https://username@....
- Tried to use SSH
- Tried to use the http.extraHeader in the git command with the header being

  ```
  Authorization: Basic Base64Encoded(uname:PAT)
  ```
- Tried to use the http.extraHeader in the git command with the header being

  ```
  Authorization: Bearer PAT
  ```
- Tried to use the VSCode client. It generates the PAT by itself but still cannot authenticate and clone.
- Tried to use the Rider VSTS client. It generates the PAT by itself but still cannot authenticate and clone.
- Tried to use the git credentials manager for Linux. It promps the Code and when we authenticate in the browser, it generates a PAT successfully. Still, after that cannot authenticate.

Any clue why this is not working?

Comment: Did you try to use SSH key authentication?

Comment: Can you clone using username (email) and password (not PAT)?

Comment: No. I want to use HTTPS. 
As the question states, yes I tried usename and password but same result.

Comment: This is setting the port. `https://usename:token@myorganization.visualstudio.com:443/myproject/_git/myrepo/`

Answer (score 44):

I have had success using PAT like this;

1. Copy clone URL for your repository e.g.

   `git clone https://<domain>.visualstudio.com/<domain>/_git/<repository>`
2. After you have copied your PAT use as:

   `git clone https://<PAT>@<domain>.visualstudio.com/<domain>/_git/<repository>`

No Username nor password should be required as the PAT should suffice.

Comment: This works, however I had to add / substitute <project> and <repo>  - e.g. git clone https://<PAT>@mydomain.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo

Comment: Yep it works on Mac OS Big Sur as well. Running the command on terminal in the VS Code.

Comment: This works with new dev.azure.com addresses too. In fact the only style I could get to work.

My particular case: https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_git/<repo>

Comment: This worked on my case, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I use Azure Devops 2019 on promise but your suggestion does not work.
when I've executed ```git clone https://<PAT>@<domain>.visualstudio.com/<domain>/_git/<repository>``` command need password.

Answer (score 27):

I've experienced the same issue, and spent quite a while searching for a solution. I finally came across [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts) which contained a solution in the comments section by [Martinius79](https://github.com/Martinius79).

In short, it was required to pass the username and PAT, encoded as base64, through git http.extraheaders in order for it to authenticate.

100% Credit to the original author, just including it here to assist others in locating it:

> Example:
>   git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Basic TXlHaXRTeW5jVXNlcjo2bHFqNXJkcHEzdXBxZWVmd2o3bDduZXN5NTR3d3gxNHFobDVlanl5NTVkb2g0M3d4YzRh" clone https://tfs.address/tfs/Collection/Project/_git/RepoName
>
> Used basic token BASE64 encoded: TXlHaXRTeW5jVXNlcjo2bHFqNXJkcHEzdXBxZWVmd2o3bDduZXN5NTR3d3gxNHFobDVlanl5NTVkb2g0M3d4YzRh
>
> Basic Token BASE64 decoded: MyGitSyncUser:6lqj5rdpq3upqeefwj7l7nesy54wwx14qhl5ejyy55doh43wxc4a
>
> Token is constructed from :
>   In this example:
>   Fictional user name: MyGitSyncUser
>   Used PAT: 6lqj5rdpq3upqeefwj7l7nesy54wwx14qhl5ejyy55doh43wxc4a

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is definitely the _correct_ answer.  I struggled with this for a while on Ubuntu, after having successfully testing it on Windows using the plain PAT (without needing to Base64 encode).  Note that you _need_ to have a username in base64 encode as per the example.  Tried without and it does not work.

Comment: For me this is not working. I.e. I get the same result as without setting the -c http.extraheader

Comment: I added this to my .bashrc:

`AZURE_PAT="<your PAT>";
AZURE_AUTH_HEADER=$(echo -n "anything:$AZURE_PATH" |base64 -w0);
alias azure-git='git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Basic ${AZURE_AUTH_HEADER}"'`

Comment: After trying many answers on SO. this fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I too struggled for hours trying all the other suggestions but adding an encoded copy of Azure DevOps username + ":" + PAT into the git clone command worked perfectly...thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This [official guide procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts) worked for me, but with one important point. When base64-encoding, one must put attention to non-printable characters.

The guide says:

```
MY_PAT=yourPAT      # replace "yourPAT" with your actual PAT
B64_PAT=$(printf ":$MY_PAT" | base64)
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}" clone 
https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

Using "echo" instead of "printf" would insert a newline char, changing the base64 string (probably would work also with "echo -n" but I haven't tried).
Also, do not include the username, as per the snippet above.

Used git 2.17.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Well this just ended 2 days of frantic debugging. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and got it solved using HTTPS only.

I figured out that I had to use the terminal only rather than using any "GUI shortcuts" dev.azure provides since they are meant for a git-credential-manager which works fine on windows but is broken for Ubuntu.

Apparently, the dev.azure git repository has a different credentials (which you need to set up) rather than your Microsoft account credential.

Let's say my Microsoft account username is johndoe@outlook.com, with its password Jd1986

This credential will **NOT** work if you try for git cloning, as you *need* to generate git credential for your project and then use it.

You can generate git credential from here,
[image]

After this, Save it and use the set credential.
[image]

Go to your terminal, and use the HTTP url for git clone and enter the given credential. This worked for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Azure DevOps -> Azure DevOps repo imports. I had been getting the errors: Clone URL is incorrect.
Clone URL requires authorization.

Comment: you don't need to do this. All you need is this for cloning. accessToken is System.AccessToken $"git -c http.extraheader=\"AUTHORIZATION: bearer {accessToken}\" clone --depth 1 {repo1.ProjectTargetUrl}".BashOut(); And BashOut is just a helper method to convert to a bash command with escape chars

Comment: And if you need creds generate and ssh cred and apply it to the mac. I believe that is alternate credentials which is very unsafe. You should not use them and Microsoft explicitly says not too.

Comment: I use Azure DevOps 2019 and it does not have ```generate git credential```

Answer (score 2):

**Git http.extraheader & bearer**

YAML style Pipelines can use the preset variable [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken).  After examining the formal 'Checkout ...' step at the beginning of the Pipeline I found this step to work in my script:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" clone --depth 1 https://my-org@dev.azure.com/my-org/my-proj/_git/my-repo'
```

Note that Azure DevOps [job authorization scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) may affect this

Comment: You can issue the same command without needing yaml. This is the correct answer

Comment: One caveat, is the access token cannot push because the pipelines are read only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known regression in curl 7.61.0, which ships with Ubuntu 18.10.  The regression was fixed in curl 7.61.1, but Ubuntu 18.10 doesn't have this fix yet.  See (and upvote) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1805203

Answer (score 1):

1. Login into Azure Dev Ops portal.
2. Go to Project you wish to clone.
3. Select Repo from left menu.
4. Click on Clone from right top corner.
5. Click Generate Git Credential
6. Enter given https clone url, username & password where you are cloning repository.
7. you are done!

Answer (score -2):

Ensure you are a member of the **Contributor** group and that your **permissions** are not limited for your user or group on the azure repo.

Azure **Contributor** group has per default permission to clone, fetch, and explore the contents of a repository; also, can create, comment on, vote, and contribute to pull requests.

Any of this permissions can be edited by members of the [Project Administrator Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions) or those having **Manage permissions** set to Allow for Git repositories as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions).

If your group or user does not have the permission to clone the repository, you will get the behaviour described by the question.

Comment: Please explain how/why this fixes the described problem.

Comment: Does not answer anything

Answer (score -4):

Try : 
First delete the git credentials from Credential manager.
Try Generating a new personal access token to resolve this error

[image: Error]

Go to security ->Personal access token->Add
Give Description, select All scopes, click Create Token.

[image: PAT]

Copy the token and store it for later use. This token can now be used in place of password for the git user.

[image: Token]

Comment: The error you mention in this post is totally unrelated to my problem.